# MS Access Backend hosting

Tags: nas, microsoft-access, windows-server, freenas

I currently have an MS Access database, split into frontend and backend. The backend is hosted on a Windows 10 pro PC with network sharing. The frontend is distributed to users running a mix of Windows 7 & 10, with Access 2013 & 2016. 
I am getting hangups due to too many network connections. Windows OS restricts to 20. I need to upgrade to a server. 
Can I use a linux based NAS, or do I need a Windows Server for access to run properly?
Thanks

Comment: You should migrate your access database to a real server, for example MS SQL server

Comment: @DavidPostill I understand. However I didn't build this database. My question was if it will run off a nas drive.